# Approximating Huber cost function with $n$:th roots of deg. $n$ polynomials?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, soft-question, asymptotics

$n$:th roots of monic polynomials (of order $n$) have the curious property:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0} = x + k$$

They have linear asymptotes.

Now, enter [Huber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcFx5.png) loss function.

$$L_\delta(a)=\cases{\frac 1 2 a^2\hspace{2cm} \text{ for } |a|<\delta,\\\delta (|a|-\frac 1 2 \delta)\hspace{0.75cm} \text{for } |a|>\delta}$$

It is quadratic for small arguments, but linear once we get outside of $\delta$. Will functions of the form prescribed above be able to approximate our function arbitrarily well? If not, why not?

---

Just to complement the great answer below, I made some numeric experiments. With numeric optimization methods for example in GNU Octave we find approximations with polynomials of order 2,4 and 6:

Errors to the left. Curve shape to the right.

[image]
[image]

I think the second order parabola stops at $x=1$ and there the line starts.

Comment: What exactly are the $c_k$ and what do they have to do with roots of what polynomial? Is the limit really $x\to\infty$ and how can there be any $x$ on the right side?

Comment: The $c_k$ are design coefficients of the polynomial. We are not looking for roots of any polynomial. Yes the limit is to infinity. That the root of the polynomial has a linear asymptote as $x\to \infty$

Comment: So you are using $$x\sqrt[n]{1+c_{n-1}x^{-1}+c_{n-2}x^{-2}+...}=x\cdot\left[1+\frac1n(c_{n-1}x^{-1}+c_{n-2}x^{-2}+...)+O(x^{-2})\right]=x+\frac{c_{n-1}}n+O(x^{-1}).$$ Note that the root is up to interpretation if the contents inside it is negative or complex. // And you want your construction to be valid for $x>0$? Or use even $n$ so that you can extract $|x|$ to get something valid for $|x|\to\infty$.

Comment: If you want to stay symmetric, the polynomial has to be symmetric. There has to be a constant term, else the behavior at $x=0$ is singular. So you do not get to the value $0$ at $x=0$. Further, around $x=0$ you get $$\sqrt[n]{c_0}\left[1+\frac{c_1}{c_0}x+\frac{c_2}{c_0}x^2+O(x^3)\right].$$ So if an asymmetric solution is ok, one could use $$\sqrt[2m]{x^{2m}+2ma x^{2m-1}+a^{2m}(1+x^2)}-a$$ which should be $\sim|x|$ for large $x$ and flat at $x=0$. But then there will be negative values under the root, from about $x=-2ma$ to about $-a/\sqrt[2m-1]{2m}$.

Comment: Very good observations. I will try update question.

Comment: @LutzL you are correct, I just saw the value of subtracting $a$. Seems to work nice. Feel free to write an answer if you want to.

Comment: I think that your expression "roots of polynomials" is misleading. Writing it ""$n$-th root of a $n$-th degree polynomial" would be less harmful.

Comment: @JeanMarie okay I hopefully fixed it to better expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me reformulate your assertion under the precise form :

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{x^n+q(x)}-x\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}c_{n-1} \ \ \ \text{where} \ \ \ q(x):=c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0 \tag{1}$$

and prove it. Indeed :

$$\sqrt[n]{x^n+q(x)}=\sqrt[n]{x^n\left(1+\dfrac{q(x)}{x^n}\right)}=x\sqrt[n]{1+\dfrac{q(x)}{x^n}}.\tag{2}$$

Now, let us use the first two terms of the classical "generalized Newton binomial expansion" :

$$(1+X)^{a}=1+aX+\dfrac{a(a-1)}{2}X^2+... \text{with} \ \ a:=\dfrac{1}{n}, \ \ X:=\dfrac{q(x)}{x^n}$$

expression (2) becomes :

$$x \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\dfrac{q(x)}{x^n}\right)=x+\dfrac{1}{n}\dfrac{c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...}{x^{n-1}} \approx x+\dfrac{1}{n}c_{n-1}\tag{3}$$

(this approximation being valid for $x \to \infty$).

Plugging (3) into (2), (1) is established.

Remark : Our derivation, strictly speaking, is valid "for $x$ sufficiently large", i.e., for $x$ such that the expression under the radical symbol is always positive. Otherwise, we should have taken absolute values under the radical sign in order to prevent ambiguous cases.

---

Besides, I don't see any connection with Huber loss function.

Comment: Could you please show an example on this rather strange theory? Thanks.

Comment: Is this question addressed to me or to the OP ? Moreover, what do you mean by "theory" ?

Comment: The question is addressed to you, it looks like you know more about it. I should probably say the "assertion" rather than "theory", I mean the limit expression. It looks new and strange to me. Thanks. If this is inappropriate, I can open a new question. Thanks again.

Comment: @NoChance maybe it makes more sense to you if you look at JeanMaries expression $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left\{x\sqrt[n]{1+\dfrac{q(x)}{x^n}}\right\}$ we can see that $x^n$ will dominate $q(x)$ for large $x$ and limit will be $x$ times $1+0=1$, so $x$ times $1$, which will behave arbitrarily close to $x$.

Comment: That is nice-Thank you much.

Comment: @NoChance : saying that a function with equation $y=f(x)$ has an asymptote with equation $y=x+m$ is the same as saying that $f(x)-x$ has a limit $m$. My contribution is an explicit formula for this value $m=\dfrac{1}{n}C_{n-1}$ (and its proof).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the clarification. It clear now.